# MySql : Fastest way to Select then Calculate and Insert Millions Data

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have around 5 million rows of data in `Table A`. I need to calculate (mathematical) each row of data using data from `Table B` and then insert the result into `Table C`.

Its pretty simple if i don't have large datas by just 
1.ResultA =  select from table A 
2.ResultB =  select from table B 
Foreach(Result A) do calculation, prepare all into an array then store in table C using `LOAD DATA LOCAL`

**Most of the time spend is in this foreach(Result A).**. But I can't seems to find a way to get rid of this foreach because i hav to calculate each row of data.

But when I do this with this task of 5 millions data. Its taking too much time.( Estimated to be taking around 50 minutes. )

Any suggestion how to optimize the process to make it much faster?

Comment: Did you profile whether time consumption is driven by queries or by calculations? A [MCVE] would be helpful...

Comment: @jkalden I just updated my question. Most of time spend is in Foreach(result A) . Calculation is pretty simple as its just one addition and division.

Comment: Could be badly written database queries, could be that you're trying to do the real work in PHP when it woud be better done in the database itself, could be that you need decent indexing for the selects, any number of possibilities, and we can't really see what it is that you're actually trying to do

Comment: Can you try to use matric calculus to avoid the row-by-row calculation?

Comment: @MarkBaker You are right. But query are not slow ( i did simple query time check ) its just foreach row calculation. Thanks.jkalden I'll try look into it.

Comment: Is this running on an extremely low-power device?  Otherwise, I've having trouble seeing how 10 million basic ops takes 50 minutes (that's like 0.0033MIPS).  Is it possible your queries are doing an unfortunate join and you are ending up with an insane number of rows?

Comment: use the "explain" mysql, and work your index, LOAD DATA and the fastest command to ready inserted or replaced given. Large treatment are long, it's normal.
After you can always tried to separate these treatments on multiple table.
For when the indexes become too large, they slow down the processing of select.
Reviews The other solution is to use a database "no sql" for your big treatments, which will largely be faster.

Comment: What is it you need to calculate with PHP? Maybe you can write a MySQL stored procedure instead.